# How to capture audio video in internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video-capture

Main objective here is to get webcam audio video feed.I know about webrtc and webrtc pretty much the solution that i am looking for also there a good number of tutorials that explains how it works. But the problem is that webrtc not support IE and safari.Safrai is not an issue as not needed at this time for my need .BUt IE is the one which i need the most .

Looking for the solution one the internet ,got a few using silverlight and other 3rd party plugin that need to install first on the end user's browser.But don't want this type of implementation.

IS there any way to implement a webrtc like similar implementation  for IE.

BTW I am following this [LInk](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) for my implementation ...

Comment: have you tried this one? https://code.google.com/p/webrtc4all/ it says it got support for both IE9+ and safari

Answer (score 2):

RTC is not supported in Internet Explorer. It's worth noting that [support for Internet Explorer is dropping](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support?platform=hootsuite), quickly. If you wish to capture video and audio, you'll need to use a third-party plugin. There is no other way.